# javafx 8 create images on button on hover using css

Tags: css, image, button, hover, javafx-8

I'm making a Mario themed application, and I would like the buttons to have the effect that when the user hovers over it with his/her mouse, a mushroom (image) appears next to the text of the button, and disappears when the mouse moves away.I'm trying to do this using css.

How can one do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the hover pseudoclasses.

```
.button:hover{
    -fx-graphic: url('your_path_to_image');
}
```

---

### Complete Example

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button button = new Button("Click");
        HBox container = new HBox(button);
        container.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(container, 200, 200);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/style.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**style.css**

```
.button:hover{
    -fx-graphic: url('http://files.softicons.com/download/game-icons/super-mario-icons-by-sandro-pereira/png/16/Mushroom%20-%201UP.png');
}
```

**Image**

[image]

**On hover**

[image]